# Flutter saves emoji as a question mark

Tags: sql-server, flutter, emoji

I have a flutter app that saves text via an API to an SQL Server database. The problem is that if I try and save text that contains an emoji it gets saved in the db as a question mark. So consequently when the text gets displayed again it displays the question mark instead of the emoji.

Is there a way to pass the text containing the emoji so that it gets encoded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, emoji's are just the unicode characters. Your MS SQL database should support unicode. MS SQL Server, in general, supports unicode but the one on Azure doesn't support. Please check with your database.

In order to save the text with emoji, you need to have the column of type NVARCHAR. And you have to write 'N' before the actula data, like below :

```
INSERT INTO tbluser(postreplies) VALUES (N' ');
```

Comment: its save fine, Thanks